# Floating a div without setting a width

Tags: css, responsive-design

Trying to float two divs within a wrapper div, where only the sidebar has a %-based width. The main div needs to stretch based on the width of the sidebar, filling the remaining area of the wrapper (i.e. it doesn't have a width set itself).

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="sidebar"></div>
   <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BphXG/4/) to get the idea:

I've tried all kinds of variations of `inline-block`, `float:left`, `float:right` etc and just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in two different ways:

---

### I. The SIDE and BODY has own scrollers

In this case, `sidebar` will has own scrollbar, and `main` will has own scrollbar too.
This method is good when you don't want to scroll your sidebar, while scrolling the main content.

Make your wrapper in full page dimension:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And CSS for sidebar will be:

```
.sidebar {
    background: blue;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And your main div:

```
.main {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

- `[!]` You can check this method at [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/WkSaR/1/).

---

### II. The SIDE and BODY will scroll by WRAPPER

In this case, both `sidebar` and `main` content will be scroll by the main `wrapper`.
For creating this, just `float` both sidebar and main content.

```
.main {
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar {
    background: blue;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

- `[!]` You can check this method at [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/WkSaR/2/).

Comment: Thanks. This method means that the sidebar just overlaps the content div though.

Comment: @SeekingCharlie No it wont overlap the content div. The content div is just beside it.

Comment: @NOX I can't seem to put a margin between the two though? It applies the margin, but as they "overlap", the gap isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you provided:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

I think this css will do what you're asking:

```
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

.main {
    margin:0 0 0 20%;
}
```

Just assuming you don't want the .main div content wrapping below the .sidebar one; and .main will take the remaining space of however wide the parent .wrapper is.

Support should go back a ways, too.

Answer (score 0):

here with your solution

http://jsfiddle.net/YKPy5/

```
<pre>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  .wrapper {
    background: 000;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 200px;
}
  .main {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 200px;
}
  .sidebar {
    background: blue;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

</pre>
```

please note: without width any inline / inline-block element do not create any space. you have to add content / text to get the effect,